# javascript object literal and self-executing functions

Tags: javascript

I'm studying object literals and self-executing functions in Javascript. Looking through some YUI code I came across some methods of an object literal that execute themselves. My question is why the following code does not alert 'Ohai Mark!';

```
var bar = {
    alert: function () {
        window.alert('Ohai Mark!');
    },
    init: (function () {
        bar.alert();
    }())
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To explain in detail:

```
> var bar = {
```

In javascript, declarations are processed first so *bar* exists as a variable before execution begins.

```
>     alert: function () {
>         window.alert('Ohai Mark!');
>     },
>     init: (function () {
>         bar.alert();
>     }())
```

*bar* will be assigned a value **after** the expression on the right hand side is evaluated. During that evaluation, *bar* has whatever value it had when the statement (the entire line) was reached. It is currently *undefined*, and so it does not have an *alert* property yet.

```
> };
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. So I suppose a better way to do it would be to eliminate the self-invoking method and just have the line bar.init() after the assignment? How would _you_ go about doing this? I saw another question that suggested doing something like

`var bar = (function () { function alert() { alert('hi'); } return {alert: alert}}())` then simply calling alert like so `bar.alert()`. Do you think that is a better way?

Comment: Zach, that's an excellent way to properly scope your functions.  This way, every function can be scoped in the 'bar' namespace, and this further allows you to have private / public functions.  Go for it!

Answer (score 3):

When executing the code, "bar" is defined but not yet assigned the resultant JSON object at the point which the init() method is defined (and about to assigned to the *bar* object) **[EDITED]**.  As init's function-scope is properly defined, I would declare the function there, like so:

```
var bar = {
  init: (function () {
      var alert = function () {
        window.alert('Ohai Mark!');
      };

      alert(); //this will execute the code above
  }())
};
```

See [Javascript Garden#namespaces and scopes](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.scopes).  **[EDIT]** You might think this akin to:

```
(function() {
  var c = c + 1;
})();
```

Comment: +1 , but more correctly, *bar* is defined before any code is run, but the object with property *alert* has not yet been assigned at the point that the function is called.

Comment: Wow, excellent catch and you made that way harder to explain.  Further feedback would be truly appreciated (see edit)

Comment: I would explain it as *bar* has not been assigned a value until after the RHS expression (not "JSON object") has been evaluated, so calling *bar.alert()* during evaluation of the expression (i.e. before it exists) results in an error.

Comment: The referenced article has a large number of errors, it should not be offered to anyone inexperienced with javascript or ECMAScript.

Comment: And here I've been assuming Javascript Garden had it all right.  Do you have something to reference faults / inaccuracies of JSG?

Comment: there is no link on the page to send comments to, some examples: `everything gets defined in one globally shared namespace` ignores function scope. `A defines a variable called foo in the global scope` no, it doesn't, in that example *foo* is created as a property of the global obejct **when the code executes**. Explanation of "hoisting" is poor, doesn't mention variable instationation phase (which it should), so mixing "hoisting" with scope (different concepts). There are many others—the general thrust is ok, but there are many, many casual errors.

Comment: Just like mine (i.e. a casual error).  It's still an incredible resource, even if you have to take it with a grain of salt.  Thanks for the info here.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I couldn't do this though, I need the functions to be defined as methods in the object so that other methods can call it and stuff. Thanks for helping me understand the problem, though! :)